# Jquery script is it possible to make smaller or more effecient

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have a webpage with six icons followed by a header and button for each. Currently I have it working as when you hover over img-1, header-1 and button-1 all hover the same color so on for the following. I was wondering as my jquery im still new and havent mastered it by any means but I call out every single change I want, I was wondering if there is a way to consolidate it or make it easier if I want to change it but still have it hover and change colors to the corresponding divs

Ive set up a snippet of what I  have on jfiddle an as you can see on my jquery list i have a long list of stuff doing the same thing

Thanks any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated to help me in any future sites I write

http://jsfiddle.net/udegrbnr/

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
<div class="container-1">
<div class="visible-1 upgradea-1 upgradea imgnone-1"><img     src="http://placehold.it/250/000000/000000" alt=""></div>
<div class="hidden-1 upgradea-1 upgradea otherimg-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/250/db232b/000000" alt=""></div>
</div>
<h3 class="upgradea upgrade otherimg" style="text-align: center;">Upgrade Alert</h3>
<div class="aligncenter"><a class="button small button custom fusion-button button-flat button-square button-small button-custom button-1 buttonshadow-no button-upgrade otherimg" target="_self" href="#"><span class="fusion-button-text">Learn More</span></a></div>    </div>

<div style="width:30%;float:left;">
<div class="container-1">
<div class="visible-1 contracta contractnone-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/250/000000/000000" alt=""></div>
<div class="hidden-1 contracta contractimg-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/250/344da1/000000" alt=""></div>
</div>
<h3 class="contracta contractimg" style="text-align: center;">Contract End&nbsp;Alert</h3>
<div class="aligncenter"><a class="button small button custom fusion-button button-flat button-square button-small button-custom button-3 buttonshadow-no contracta contractimg" target="_self" href="#"><span class="fusion-button-text">Learn More</span></a></div></div></div>
```

and here is all 6 divs i have for my jquery as i feel its alot and can be simplified hopefully

Like i have seen the "this" command but dont know if that could be applied

```
$(function(){
     $(".upgradea , .button-upgrade").hover(function(){
   $(".upgradea , .button-upgrade").toggleClass("changecolor");

 });
    $(".button-upgrade-1").hover(function(){
    $(".button-upgrade-1").toggleClass("changecolor-1");

 });

  $(".flexa ").hover(function(){
   $(".flexa").toggleClass("changecolor-2");

});

 $(".contracta ").hover(function(){
   $(".contracta").toggleClass("changecolor-3");

});

 $(".mileagea ").hover(function(){
  $(".mileagea").toggleClass("changecolor-4");

 });

 $(".warrantya").hover(function(){
    $(".warrantya").toggleClass("changecolor-5");

 });

   $(".otherimg").hover(function(){
    $(".otherimg-1").toggleClass("changeimg");

 });

 $(".otherimg").hover(function(){
  $(".imgnone-1").toggleClass("hidden-1");

 });

   $(".fleximg").hover(function(){
   $(".fleximg-1").toggleClass("changeimg");

 });

 $(".fleximg").hover(function(){
    $(".flexnone-1").toggleClass("hidden-1");

});

   $(".contractimg").hover(function(){
   $(".contractimg-1").toggleClass("changeimg");

});

 $(".contractimg").hover(function(){
    $(".contractnone-1").toggleClass("hidden-1");

});
```

});

Comment: Possibly a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Read http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you ill try that out, I had no idea that this was a thing now

Comment: Is there any reason that you're not using the css [`:hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) pseudo-class?

Comment: I was using that, but to make everything work an  hover at the same time, this was the only way I could make it work with my skill level

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason not to use CSS for *all* of this. If you target the children of a hovered parent, you can style it however you like. For example:

```
.parent:hover h3, .parent:hover .child a {
   color: red;
}
```

This CSS could absolutely be further cleaned up, there are a lot of redundant CSS rules and unnecessary containers, I just didn't want to stray too far from the example you provided.

http://jsfiddle.net/qk53a5q4/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, re-think your CSS.

Instead of having a specific class for each hover/changeimg/changecolor state, have one class that states **what** the thing is then one class for each **state**.

HTML:

```
<button class="button-1 hover">Button 1</button>
<button class="button-2 hover">Button 2</button>
```

CSS:

```
.button-1.hover { /* styles */ }
.button-2.hover { /* styles */ }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.button-1, .button-2').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Leave a comment when you down-vote. This is a perfectly valid solution. OP obviously does not understand that CSS classes can be combined.